# Sqlite3 - SELECT syntax error?

Tags: python, list, sqlite, zip

I am trying to check values in rows in a table against certain lists and get the number of matching rows, but keep getting a syntax error that I just can't seem to get past:

```
c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE Column1 > Column2 AND 
(X = ?, Y = ?, Z = ?)", zip(listX, listY, listZ))
number = c.fetchall()
print(number)
```

X, Y and Z are column names. I get:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

I had something similar but using `INSERT` instead of `SELECT` and worked fine. I'm new to sqlite3; does `SELECT` use a different syntax than `INSERT` when they use `WHERE`? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple comparisons must be separated with a logic operator like AND or OR (what should the comma mean?):

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE Column1 > Column2
  AND X = ?
  AND Y = ?
  AND Z = ?;
```

Alternatively, you could use row values, but your Python probably is not recent enough to support it:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE Column1 > Column2
  AND (X, Y, Z) = (?, ?, ?);
```

And if you want to check against multiple sets of values, you have to put add the appropriate number of checks to the SQL query, or just execute it multiple times:

```py
number = 0
for xyz in zip(listX, listY, listZ):
    c.execute('''SELECT count(*) FROM myTable
                 WHERE Column1 > Column2
                   AND X = ?
                   AND Y = ?
                   AND Z = ?''', xyz)
    number += c.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: For the first example I get: `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type` - X, Y, Z are type `TEXT` and the lists contain text strings, but - I'm thinking maybe something to do with the zipped lists as values? And the second try returns `sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`